# I'm creating graph by using canvasjs, it is working fine with static values but not with dynamic ones

Tags: jquery, canvasjs

Code:

```
$('.subjctList_sbjctWisePrfrmnce').live('click',function(){
    $("#main-content").empty();
    $("#main-content").append(
             "<div class='tab-pane padding-bottom30 active fade in'>"+
             "<div id='chartContainer' style='height: 300px; width: 100%;'>"+

                "</div>"+
                "</div>"
);

    var fa1=$(this).attr('data-fa1');
    var fa2=$(this).attr('data-fa2');
    var term1totalFA=$(this).attr('data-totalfa1');
    var sa1=$(this).attr('data-sa1');
    var term1Total=$(this).attr('data-trm1gtotal');
    var fa3=$(this).attr('data-fa3');
    var fa4=$(this).attr('data-fa4');
    var term2totalFA=$(this).attr('data-totalfa2');
    var sa2=$(this).attr('data-sa2');
    var term2Total=$(this).attr('data-trm2gtotal');
    var grandTotal=$(this).attr('data-anualtotal');
```

//getting dynamic values in these variables like fa1, fa2 etc.
When we pass these values in `dataPoints` array we are not able to create our graph correctly.
Whereas when we pass static values in same variable it is working fine.

```
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        theme: "theme2",//theme1
        title:{
            text: "Basic Column Chart - CanvasJS"              
        },
        animationEnabled: false,   // change to true
        data: [              
        {
            // Change type to "bar", "splineArea", "area", "spline", "pie",etc.
            type: "column",
            dataPoints: [
                { label: "FA1",  y: fa1  },
                { label: "FA2", y: 15  },
                { label: "SA1", y: 25  },
                { label: "Total Fa1",  y: 30  },
                { label: "Term1 Total",  y: 28  }
            ]
        }
        ]
    });
    chart.render();
}
```

Comment: Try with `y: parseInt(fa1)`